# Deserialization not working properly anymore after updating message

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tokio, rust-tonic, prost

maybe I'm not seeing the forest for the trees anymore and if I do, I'm sorry, but I've been stuck on an issue now for a few hours. I updated a message in my proto file by adding a field (includeObsolete):

```
message GetAllDocumentsRequest {
    RequestHeader header = 1;
    bool include_obsolete= 2;
}
```

The respective code is built correctly as far as I can tell (at least I can access the field include_obsolete inside GetAllDocumentsRequest), but whenever I print the request in my grpc service, the field include_obsolete is set to `false`.

```
async fn get_all_documents(
        &self,
        request: Request<GetAllDocumentsRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<GetDocumentsReply>, Status> {
        println!("Request: {:?}", request); // here include_obsolete  is always false
        foo();
        bar();
        ...
```

Here's the request I use in Postman:

```
{
    "include_obsolete": true,
    "header": {
        "comment": {
            "actionType": "action",
            "comment": "elit sit esse",
            "createdBy": "in dolore enim",
            "createdDate": "3410",
            "ID": 45
        },
        "messageType": "officia est",
        "senderAddress": "aute sed irure anim labore",
        "senderId": "mollit sunt",
        "token": "dolore dolor",
        "user": "erwin"
    }
}
```

And for reference the output of println!:

```
Request: Request { metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"grpc-accept-encoding": "identity,deflate,gzip", "accept-encoding": "identity", "user-agent": "grpc-node-js/1.8.10", "content-type": "application/grpc", "te": "trailers"} }, message: GetAllDocumentsRequest { header: Some(RequestHeader { sender_address: "aute sed irure anim labore", sender_id: "mollit sunt", user: "erwin", comment: Some(Comment { id: 45, created_date: 3410, created_by: "in dolore enim", action_type: "action", comment: "elit sit esse" }), message_type: Some("officia est"), token: Some("dolore dolor") }), include_obsolete: false }, extensions: Extensions }
```

All other fields are printed correctly whenever I change the values in the request.
I also tried running cargo clean already, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually with Postman, because for whatever reason it did not send the updated version of the JSON request and just skipped the newly added field. After re-importing the API it worked.